# haskell fibonacci - cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]

Tags: haskell

I was trying to get an infinite list of fibonacci numbers in haskell but the following code would not compile:

```
fib1 x = fib1 (x : (last $ init x) + (last x))
result1 = fib1 [1,2]
```

I eventually got it to work with this code:

```
fib2 x y = head y : fib2 y (zipWith (+) x y)
result2 = fib2 [0,1] [1,1]
```

Still, I do not understand why the first code snippet did not compile. The error is below. I am just looking for an answer as to why the first one doesn't compile but the second does.

```
p2.hs:3:16:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `fib1', namely
      `(x : (last $ init x) + (last x))'
    In the expression: fib1 (x : (last $ init x) + (last x))

p2.hs:3:21:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the first argument of `(+)', namely `(last $ init x)'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely
      `(last $ init x) + (last x)'
    In the first argument of `fib1', namely
      `(x : (last $ init x) + (last x))'

p2.hs:3:44:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    Expected type: [[a0]]
      Actual type: [a0]
    In the first argument of `last', namely `x'
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely `(last x)'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely
      `(last $ init x) + (last x)' Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the first code sample is that there is no way you could write a type annotation for it. It would be infinite. Let's try it anyway:

`fib1 x = fib1 (x : (last $ init x) + (last x))`

First let's simplify it, because we can replicate the same problem without the `last` and `init` stuff:

`fib1 x = fib1 (x : undefined)`

What is the type of `fib1`'s argument. On the left, we only see `x` with no more information about it. We can assume it has some type `a`. On the right hand side, we try to call the function with argument which must be a list (because it is constructed by `:` operator). Elements of the list start with `x`, which has type `a`. Therefore, the type of `fib1`'s argument here is `[a]`. Since we can't call a function with arguments of two different types, even on left side `x` must have type `[a]`. But this forces us to update the type on the rigth side to `[[a]]`. And then again on the left. This process will never stop, the type will grow and grow, because there is no way to unify `a` with `[a]`. Therefore there is no valid type for the expression and GHC will reject it.

On the other hand, the second snippet does not have the problem.

`fib2 x y = head y : fib2 y (zipWith (+) x y)`

We can easily ask GHCi the type of this function, and it will happily answer us:

`Prelude> let fib2 x y = head y : fib2 y (zipWith (+) x y)
Prelude> :t fib2
fib2 :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`

That type is perfectly finite.

Comment: Good explanation.  @Jeff Lins, the first step when you get problems like this is to add type declarations to your functions. (or even make a habit of always adding them) Then either you get more precise errors from the compiler,  or -- as in this case -- find the problem yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Before I posted the question I tried to provide the following type annotation: fib1 :: Num a => [a] -> [a]. But obviously that didn't work. I don't understand why it changes the right side to [[a]]. Because [a] : [a] should result in just [a]. Why does it wrap the list in another list?

Comment: @JeffLins You have the type of `(:)` wrong; it is not `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` but `a -> [a] -> [a]`. But even then you would have a problem, because `last` and `init` are not (obviously) going to return a list.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Now this answer makes perfect sense to me! The type mix-up seems to be where the problem started.